# R: Error in function "nls" for my datset

Tags: r, exponential, nls, model-fitting

I have data with climatological pressure values and the heights of the stations where the pressure was measured. I would like to fit an exponential model to them. The data look like this:

```
x
 [1]  539  575 1320  438 1840  496  316  552  325  386 1599 1073  556 1029 1661
[16] 2472 1594 1197  910 1035  596  646  420  516 1980 1045 2287  440  419 1611
[31]  577 3580  484 1018 1669  745 1974  366  273  454  203  588 1427  405 1403
[46]  485  490 2106  990 3305 1078  455  300 1638 1708  438 1303  482  775 2502
[61]  457 2690  422 1638  555  426

y
[1] 954.1 951.4 867.2 964.0 813.3 958.8 979.7 950.8 978.4 971.3 835.1 894.1
[13] 952.0 904.4 833.3 751.5 839.0 882.5 912.0 899.4 947.1 942.3 968.5 961.9
[25] 801.3 893.6 769.8 965.6 965.1 836.9 949.2 653.6 959.8 900.2 830.6 928.6
[37] 800.3 971.1 983.5 963.4 992.6 947.5 848.3 969.4 858.2 959.9 959.3 787.2
[49] 900.4 677.6 893.2 962.7 981.5 834.9 827.0 966.0 870.1 961.1 925.2 749.3
[61] 962.8 734.0 968.0 836.3 950.4 966.5
```

I have first tried just to take the logarithms of the data and fit an `lm` them:

```
log.p=log(y)
log.height=log(x)
lmlog=lm(log.p~log.height)
```

But as this delivered a model that does not fit at all, I've decided to use the `nls` function having taken various tips from other posts (e.g. "start"):

```
f <- function(x,a,b) {a* exp(b * x)}
dat <- as.list(x, y)
start <- coef(nls(log(y) ~ log(f(x, a, b)), dat, start = c(a = 1, b = -1)))
nls=nls(y~ f(x,a,b), data=dat, start=start)
```

Unfortunately, even for "start", the following errors appear and I really don't know what to do anymore...

```
Error in numericDeriv(form[[3L]], names(ind), env) : 
  Missing value or an infinity produced when evaluating the model
In addition: Warning messages:
1: In min(x) : no non-missing arguments to min; returning Inf
2: In max(x) : no non-missing arguments to max; returning -Inf
```

Can anyone help?
Thanks in advance!!!

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Transforming both variables doesn't linearize the relationship:

```
plot(log(y)~log(x))
```

[image]

Instead you should only transform `y`:

```
plot(log(y)~x)
modlm <- lm(log(y)~x)
abline(modlm)
```

[image]

```
summary(modlm)

Call:
lm(formula = log(y) ~ x)

Residuals:
       Min         1Q     Median         3Q        Max 
-0.0081825 -0.0009194  0.0000952  0.0008455  0.0070058 

Coefficients:
              Estimate Std. Error t value Pr(>|t|)    
(Intercept)  6.927e+00  4.567e-04 15166.4   <2e-16 ***
x           -1.227e-04  3.516e-07  -349.1   <2e-16 ***
---
Signif. codes:  0 ‘***’ 0.001 ‘**’ 0.01 ‘*’ 0.05 ‘.’ 0.1 ‘ ’ 1

Residual standard error: 0.002185 on 64 degrees of freedom
Multiple R-squared:  0.9995,    Adjusted R-squared:  0.9995 
F-statistic: 1.219e+05 on 1 and 64 DF,  p-value: < 2.2e-16
```

Of course you can use `nls` too:

```
modnls <- nls(y~exp(a+b*x), start=list(a=coef(modlm)[[1]], b=coef(modlm)[[2]]))
plot(y~x)
xnew <- seq(min(x), max(x), by=0.5)
lines(xnew, exp(coef(modnls)[[1]]+xnew*coef(modnls)[[2]]))
```

[image]

```
summary(modnls)

Formula: y ~ exp(a + b * x)

Parameters:
    Estimate Std. Error t value Pr(>|t|)    
a  6.926e+00  4.384e-04 15797.5   <2e-16 ***
b -1.225e-04  3.831e-07  -319.7   <2e-16 ***
---
Signif. codes:  0 ‘***’ 0.001 ‘**’ 0.01 ‘*’ 0.05 ‘.’ 0.1 ‘ ’ 1

Residual standard error: 1.904 on 64 degrees of freedom

Number of iterations to convergence: 2 
Achieved convergence tolerance: 6.25e-08
```

Note how the parameter estimates of the linear and the nonlinear fit are very similar. Usually, you should choose whether to use `lm` with transformed data or `nls` with untransformed data depending on the error distribution. However, since the relationship between `y` and `x` is not very nonlinear, it doesn't matter so much here.

Comment: Thanks a lot for the help and correcting even my "stupid" errors that thoroughly! ;-)
As the data come from lower parts of the atmosphere here, the closeness of linear and nonlinear fit was to be expected and so exactly that was what I wanted to observe!